# How do I set the Navigation Bar Title as a editable text field?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I would like the user to be able to edit the title of the navigation bar. I feel like I've seen it in an app before. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried placing a `UITextField` in it?

Comment: That's possible? That's kind of what I'm asking.... I'll check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a `UINavigationController` then play around with

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = // UITextView
```

Comment: @Paul : Guess what - that core-data issue was pretty simple. I just had to reload the dataSource for the NSFetchedResultsController as soon as I delete core data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to customize your `navigationBar` and add the `UITextField` as as subView, and place it accordingly.